# cannot return delphi array in C# array

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I want to use delphi array function in C#.

My delphi code:

```
TIntegerArray = array of integer;
function Testarray(): TIntegerArray stdcall; export;
 var
   res: TIntegerArray2;
 begin
   SetLength(res, 10);
   res[5] := 55;
   Result := res;
 end;
 exports Testarray;
```

C# code:

```
[DllImport("GitaTele.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int[] Testarray();
```

Shows me error:

> Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type
>   combination.

Comment: In Delphi you return a specific type `TIntegerArray2` while in C# you try to map this to `int[]`. Howe is this supposed to work?

Comment: You can't marshal directly an array **as the retun value**. And even if you could, who would free the memory Delphy allocated for that array?

Comment: thank you. edited.my code is more than:
  TIntegerArray = array of integer;
  TIntegerArray2 = array of integer;

Comment: You cannot use arrays as a function result across DLL boundaries. Simple as that. Same reason why you cannot return strings as function results.

Comment: Pass it as a var parameter instead. But it's not as simple as that. You also have to decide which side is responsible for memory allocation / freeing. The answer varies depending on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi dynamic arrays are not valid interop types. You need to have the caller allocate the array, and then let the callee populate it.

```
procedure PopulateArray(arr: PInteger; var len: Integer); stdcall;
var
  i: Integer;
  returnArray: TArray<Integer>;
begin
  returnArray := GetArray;
  len := Min(len, Length(returnArray));
  for i := 0 to len - 1 do
  begin
    arr^ := returnArray[i];
    inc(arr);
  end;
end;
```

Do note the `export` has no meaning, is ignored, and should be removed for sake of simplicity.

From C# the calling code is:

```
[DllImport("...", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void PopulateArray(
    [In, Out]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    int[] arr,
    ref int len
);

....

int[] arr = new int[50];
int len = arr.Length;
PopulateArray(arr, ref len);
// len now contains actual length
```

Comment: Why does it needs the whole `MarshalAs`?  Can't he marshal the array directly to a `PInteger`, that is a `int*`?

Comment: You can do without the `MarshalAs`, but it allows the marshaller to optimise marshalling. On the other hand, since this example is blittable then the marshaller will just pin the array. So in that sense, `MarshalAs` serves no purpose.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `MarshalAs(MarshalAs(` you doubled the `MarshalAs` in your code.

Comment: @xanatos Belt **and** braces ;-)